# How to compare a single value to an empiric distribution and compute associated effect size

Tags: simulation, effect-size

Let say I computed X=1000 empirical p-values by comparing X_i=1000 real values (observed in a genomic experiment - one real value per gene) to S=1000 distributions to simulate background. Each single X_i value are compared to the associated S_i distribution (N=10,000 simulated observations) to computed a empirical p-value : `p_i = sum(X_i <= S_i) / N`

Now I would like to compute some kind of effect size associated to each X_i (and p_i) . Importantly I would like that these effect sizes are comparable between the different X_i. My first idea was to divide each the difference between `X_i` and `mean(S_i)` by the `sd(S_i)` . Is that ok ?

A figure is always better than a long text :

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing is to calculate a z score, which is fine, It might create a problem if the data are severly not normally distributed.

Other possibility is to calculate percentile, which is more robust, but it might be less sensitive for subjects in the tails. E.g. subject in 99% percentila can be 5 or 50 sd away from the mean

Comment: ok so in R: `percentile <- ecdf(S_i)(X_i)`